# Derivative of restriction of $f$ to parametrized line

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given $f : \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$, if we parametrize $f$ as follows

> $\phi(\theta)=f(a+\theta(x-a))$, $a\in \mathbb R^n$ is a constant vector.

What will be $\phi'(\theta)$ ?

I think it will be $\nabla f(a+\theta(x-a)) (x-a)$. But can not prove it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

(We need to  assume $f$ is differentiable.)

Your guess is correct. This is a special case of the multivariable chain rule. But in case you can't use this form of chain rule, you can argue from basic principles. The differentiability of $f$ at $a+\theta(x-a)$ means that 
$$f(a+\theta(x-a)+h) - f(a+\theta(x-a)) = \nabla f(a+\theta(x-a))\cdot h +o(|h|) $$
as $h\to 0$. Plug $h=\delta (x-a)$ where $\delta$ is small:
$$
\phi(\theta+\delta)- \phi( \theta )  = \delta\,\nabla f(a+\theta(x-a))\cdot (x-a) +o(|\delta|) $$
This latter formula says precisely what $\phi'(\theta)$ is.